# Discord.js Randomiser Command Ignoring Minimum and Maximum Values

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have this Discord bot here that contains a randomiser command - /random (built with `new SlashCommandBuilder`) - and consists of two required string options - `min` and `max` values.

This code...

```js
run: async (bot, interaction, args) => {
        const min = interaction.options.getString('min').replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '')
        const max = interaction.options.getString('max').replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '')

        parseFloat(min, parseFloat(max))

        random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min)

        console.log(min, max)

        interaction.followUp({ content: `${random}` })
        
    }
```

...extracts the strings from the user's interaction and parses them into floats. The expected result consists of a random number between the `min` value and the `max` value.

However, the randomiser does not use the `min` or `max` value and instead prints a random number regardless of what the user inputs.

I predict that is quite an inefficient method of a randomiser command. I kindly suggest assistance, and (if) any will be greatly appreciated!

**Note:** An error does not occur upon command exection.

Comment: the problem is the regex in the replace function, I've tested it [here](https://regexr.com/) and it seems working when I removed the "^" (apparently ^ makes so that the regex selects everything but the elements you're provided (here numbers) which is the exact opposite of what you want)

Comment: I logged the `min` and `max` values and they all seem to extract numbers perfectly fine to me. I don't understand the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`interaction.options.getNumber()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/CommandInteractionOptionResolver?scrollTo=getNumber) instead in your command handler; that way it's already a number:

```js
let min = interaction.options.getNumber('min');
let max = interaction.options.getNumber('max');

function randomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

await interaction.reply(`Your random number is: ${randomInt(min, max)}`);
```

Make sure, you add the options with [`addNumberOption()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/builders/stable/class/SlashCommandBuilder?scrollTo=addNumberOption) in your `deploy-commands.js` file (or whatever you named it:

```js
new SlashCommandBuilder()
  .setName('random')
  .setDescription('Generates a random number!')
  .addNumberOption((option) =>
    option
      .setName('min')
      .setDescription('Enter the minimum number')
      .setRequired(true),
  )
  .addNumberOption((option) =>
    option
      .setName('max')
      .setDescription('Enter the maximum number')
      .setRequired(true),
  )
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Such a simple solution. Kind regards!